# No terminal output for google app engine for local dev server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been using the google app engine for web app development using the python 2.7, ubuntu 12.04, and webapp2 framework.

For some strange reason when I run an app on the local dev server I can no longer view my http responses or view errors on the terminal as used to before. I don't know how it came to be this way.

Also when use my terminal to run a new using the dev_server.py command like follows,

```
ahmad@ubuntu:~/GAE$ python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py wiki
```

i get an error that the socket is being used. I remember when I ran an app I had to click ctrl+c to kill it and rerun another one.. now it seems to run in the back ground and if i try to run a different app i get a statement that the socket is being used...

here's the exact error for tyring to run a diff app on the local dev server,

```
ahmad@ubuntu:~/GAE$ python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py wiki
WARNING  2012-06-09 17:04:25,981 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2012-06-09 17:04:26,022 appengine_rpc.py:160] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2012-06-09 17:04:26,024 appcfg.py:582] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2012-06-09 17:04:26,221 appcfg.py:600] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2012-06-09 17:04:26,221 datastore_file_stub.py:518] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 125, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 121, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/ahmad/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 690, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/ahmad/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 653, in main
    persist_logs=persist_logs)
  File "/home/ahmad/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3595, in CreateServer
    server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
  File "/home/ahmad/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3623, in __init__
    request_handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
INFO     2012-06-09 17:04:26,322 datastore_stub_util.py:2410] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 3):

"Address already in use" looks like the port is already in use by some other process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the process hanging on to your port. If you use something like `ps aux` you might recognize a zombie appserver instance immediately. If not, there are [examples available](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/) to figure out which process is using a port. You might have to `kill -9` it.

If it's supposed to be in use, start dev_appserver on a different port using the `-p PORT` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run two apps simultaneously (by using two instances of dev_appserver), you're going to need to tell one of those to use a different port. It's described, with an example, in [Running the Development Web Server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver).

Ctrl-C'ing a dev_appserver on Ubuntu shouldn't cause it to wander off to run in the background. (Ctrl-Z'ing it might).

Comment: I'm only trying to run one instance and I can no longer see it.. I'm not sure how to kill it other than restart my pc

Comment: `netstat -a` to find the process that's listening on the port, then kill it.